# Restoring VS 2010 default SD desginer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I recently installed BizTalk 2010 on my VS 2010 environment that is already hooked to source control, SVN etc. BizTalk 2010 took control of my XSD designer and now it looks different.

Is there a way to revert my XSD designer without running "devenv /resetsettings"?

I'm afraid reset setting will put me back to before time and I might have to reinstall all VS.NET add-ins

Answer (score 1):

By default, BizTalk Server 2010 developer edition hooks up a graphical, hierarchical-based XSD designer, as you've noticed. This designer replaces the builtin XSD 'dataset' designer.

You can still open any .xsd file with the builtin designer. Just select the "OpenWith" option and you will be prompted with a choice of appropriate designers.

If you want to revert to using the builtin dataset designer to open .XSD project files, just perform the same steps as outlined above, but select "Set as default" when opening the file with the designer you most likely want to use from now on.

**Warning**: please, note that you will loose the ability to compile schemas in your BizTalk projects. Indeed, the BizTalk XSD designer also adds some schema metadata in you .btproj project files (specifically, the typename of the corresponding .net compiled class).